# Can dog bites cause Echinococcosis?

Tags: infection, prevention

I know that dog bites are dangerous and can give you rabies,but can a dog bite cause Echinococcosis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Dog bites are the most common type of animal bites. Only 5% of dog bites lead to local infection.*

**No, echinococcus can't be transmitted through dog bites.** Pathogens which can be transmitted by the saliva of the dog are rabies, pasteurella, capnocytophaga and brucella.

**Echinococcus could be transmitted by dogs but through fecal transmission.** Dogs are the definitive hosts for the tapeworm, Echinococcus granulosus. The adult tapeworm is present in the dog's small intestine and produces eggs that are excreted in the feces contaminating the environment. These eggs are infective to humans once ingested.

*References:* 
Kotton C. Zoonoses from dogs. Aug 2016. Uptodate. http://www.uptodate.com/contents/zoonoses-from-dogs?source=search_result&search=echinocoque&selectedTitle=6~49#H6